# Equivalency between linear algebra and analytic geometry

Tags: linear-algebra, analytic-geometry

I don't know the appropriate title, please, if anyone would be so kind to edit it properly, I would appreciate it very much.

if I have a vector $\vec{u}$ and another vector $\vec{v}$, where $\vec{u}$ lies on the line $a: (y = m_ax + c_a)$ and $\vec{v}$ lies on the line $b: (y = m_bx + c_b)$, then does it follow that vector $\vec{u+v}$ lines on line $c: (y = (m_a + m_b) x + c_a + c_b)$?

Comment: No. Have you tried looking at an example?

Comment: Draw pictures. If you take two general lines in the plane and add vectors on those lines, do you end up on a line?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan No. Can you suggest me a way to look at an example? I don't have any mathematical software, and I don't know how to use any.

Comment: You don't need software. Just use your brains. What if you add various vectors on the $x$-axis to various vectors on the $y$-axis?

Comment: @TedShifrin Will do. I was afraid the answer could be yes in 2d but not in 3d. But, from what you guys said, it is never right.

Comment: Just pick some vectors in 2 dimensions. You don't need any software to work out an example.

Comment: Is there any equivalency other than the mistaken one I was asking? A way correct way to create a relation between vector sums and equations of their lines?

Comment: There are infinitely many vectors which can lie on a given line.  Either vector of different magnitudes or vectors in opposite direction.  Summing any pair of independent vectors, could take you to any point on the plane.

Comment: @DougM yes. My question is, if vector u lies on line a, and vector v lies on line b, and u + v lies on line c, is there any meaningful relation we can make between a, b and c?

Comment: No, there is too much freedom -- too many possibilities.  If $a,b$ are not parallel, then there exists some $(u,v)$ pair such that the resulting line $c$ such that $(u+v)$ lies on $c$ can go though any point on the plane.

Comment: Another way of looking at this is that you can take the initial two lines as co-ordinate axes (not necessarily at right-angles) and build a co-ordinate grid based on the two vectors which covers the plane.